Allied Vision Vimba .Net SDK - Get images
I've been trying to access a line scan camera using the Allied Vision Vimba SDK software for some time and am using the "AsynchronousGrabConsole" example. My goal is to save around 1000 frames per second and either save them to the hard drive in parallel with the rest of the recording or to keep them in RAM and save them after the recording has finished.
Unfortunately, I'm already failing to convert the frame object into a bitmap as soon as I receive the corresponding frame event or to save it as a clone in a list. I'm probably already taking too long to do this and I'm losing frames as a result.
Based on the attached code, do you have any other ideas for me on how I can save all the frames quickly enough? Many thanks
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Force.DeepCloner;

namespace AsynchronousGrabConsole
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using AVT.VmbAPINET;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

    /// <summary>
    /// A helper class as a wrapper around Vimba
    /// </summary>
    public class VimbaHelper
    {
        private Vimba m_Vimba = null;                           // Main Vimba API entry object
        private Camera m_Camera = null;                         // Camera object if camera is open
        private bool m_Acquiring = false;                       // Flag to remember if acquisition is running
        private static BlockingCollection<Frame> frames = new BlockingCollection<Frame>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the VimbaHelper class
        /// </summary>
        public VimbaHelper()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalizes an instance of the VimbaHelper class and shuts down Vimba
        /// </summary>
        ~VimbaHelper()
        {
            // Release Vimba API if user forgot to call Shutdown
            ReleaseVimba();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current camera list
        /// </summary>
        public List<Camera> CameraList
        {
            get
            {
                // Check if API has been started up at all
                if (null == m_Vimba)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Vimba is not started.");
                }

                List<Camera> cameraList = new List<Camera>();
                CameraCollection cameras = m_Vimba.Cameras;
                foreach (Camera camera in cameras)
                {
                    cameraList.Add(camera);
                }

                return cameraList;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts up Vimba API and loads all transport layers
        /// </summary>
        public void Startup()
        {
            // Instantiate main Vimba object
            Vimba vimba = new Vimba();

            // Start up Vimba API
            vimba.Startup();
            m_Vimba = vimba;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shuts down Vimba API
        /// </summary>
        public void Shutdown()
        {
            // Check if API has been started up at all
            if (null == m_Vimba)
            {
                throw new Exception("Vimba has not been started.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("---");

            for (int i = 0; i < frames.Count; i++)
            {
                Frame frame = frames.ElementAt(i);
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1936, 2);
                frame.Fill(ref bitmap);
                bitmap.Save($"./{frame.Timestamp}-{frame.FrameID}.bmp");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            ReleaseVimba();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the continuous image acquisition and opens the camera
        /// Registers the event handler for the new frame event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The camera ID</param>
        public void StartContinuousImageAcquisition(string id)
        {
            // Check parameters
            if (null == id)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
            }

            // Check if API has been started up at all
            if (null == m_Vimba)
            {
                throw new Exception("Vimba is not started.");
            }

            // Check if a camera is already open
            if (null != m_Camera)
            {
                throw new Exception("A camera is already open.");
            }

            // Open camera
            m_Camera = m_Vimba.OpenCameraByID(id, VmbAccessModeType.VmbAccessModeFull);
            if (null == m_Camera)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("No camera retrieved.");
            }

            // Set the GeV packet size to the highest possible value
            // (In this example we do not test whether this cam actually is a GigE cam)
            try
            {
                m_Camera.Features["GVSPAdjustPacketSize"].RunCommand();
                while (false == m_Camera.Features["GVSPAdjustPacketSize"].IsCommandDone())
                {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Do nothing
            }

            m_Camera.Features["Height"].IntValue = 2;
            m_Camera.Features["ExposureTimeAbs"].FloatValue = 798;
            m_Camera.Features["AcquisitionFrameRateAbs"].FloatValue = 1000;

            bool error = true;
            try
            {
                // Register frame callback
                m_Camera.OnFrameReceived += this.OnFrameReceived;

                // Reset member variables
                m_Acquiring = true;

                // Start synchronous image acquisition (grab)
                m_Camera.StartContinuousImageAcquisition(3000);

                error = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close camera already if there was an error
                if (true == error)
                {
                    ReleaseCamera();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the image acquisition
        /// </summary>
        public void StopContinuousImageAcquisition()
        {
            // Check if API has been started up at all
            if (null == m_Vimba)
            {
                throw new Exception("Vimba is not started.");
            }

            // Check if no camera is open
            if (null == m_Camera)
            {
                throw new Exception("No camera open.");
            }

            // Close camera
            ReleaseCamera();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the frame received event
        /// The frame is displayed and eventually queued
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="frame">The received frame</param>
        private void OnFrameReceived(Frame frame)
        {
            try
            {
                frames.Add(frame.DeepClone());
            }
            finally
            {
                // We make sure to always return the frame to the API
                try
                {
                    m_Camera.QueueFrame(frame);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Unregisters the new frame event
        ///  Stops the capture engine
        ///  Closes the camera
        /// </summary>
        private void ReleaseCamera()
        {
            if (null != m_Camera)
            {
                // We can use cascaded try-finally blocks to release the
                // camera step by step to make sure that every step is executed.
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            m_Camera.OnFrameReceived -= this.OnFrameReceived;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (true == m_Acquiring)
                            {
                                m_Camera.StopContinuousImageAcquisition();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        m_Acquiring = false;
                        m_Camera.Close();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    m_Camera = null;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Releases the camera
        ///  Shuts down Vimba
        /// </summary>
        private void ReleaseVimba()
        {
            if (null != m_Vimba)
            {
                // We can use cascaded try-finally blocks to release the
                // Vimba API step by step to make sure that every step is executed.
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // First we release the camera (if there is one)
                        ReleaseCamera();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Now finally shutdown the API
                        m_Vimba.Shutdown();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    m_Vimba = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried to convert the frame to a bitmap and store it as well as to create a deep clone, so I can return the original frame to be filled again.
